# How to multi-select option from dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, html-select

I have one input box and besides that, I have on image.
After clicking on image, I am opening one drop-down there with some options which is coming from controller. If I select something from drop-down, it is going to enter in text-box. Like that we can insert multiple option from drop-down with comma separated one. 
I am able to enter single selected option from drop-down to text-box.

I need help is :

1. How to multiselect options and enter in textbox
2. How to avoid duplication option selection while entering.

This is all I need to do in Angular js.

Below is my controller:

```
              $scope.onDropDdownChange = function (dropdownFieldName, textFiledName,splitSelItem) {
                    let rpInfo = $scope.restrictedPartyInfo;
                    let selItem = rpInfo[dropdownFieldName] ? (splitSelItem ? (rpInfo[dropdownFieldName]).split("-")[0] : rpInfo[dropdownFieldName]) : '';
                    if(rpInfo[textFiledName]) {
                        var isExist = rpInfo[textFiledName].indexOf(selItem);                           
                        if(isExist)
                            rpInfo[textFiledName] += ',' + selItem;                         
                    } else {
                        rpInfo[textFiledName] = selItem;
                    }
                };
```

And below is my HTML Part:

```
            <td width="10%" class="gridInfoAddEditTableData">Customer Types*</td>
                <td width="9%" class="gridInfoAddEditTableData">                    
                    <img id="followbutton" ng-src="{{followButtonImg}}" alt="Show Hide"
                    ng-click="ShowHideCusttyp();toggleImageCustTyp()"  ng-model="restrictedPartyInfo.ShowHideCusttyp">
                    <input type="text" id="customertypes" style="width:54%" ng-click="ShowHideCusttyp();"
                    ng-model="restrictedPartyInfo.customerType"
                    ng-keydown="ShowHideCusttyp();"/>
                </td>


          <td align="center" class="gridInfoAddEditTableData">              
                 <select  multiple ng-show = "Visible" name="customerTypess"  ng-change="ShowHideCusttyp();onDropDdownChange('customerTypes','customerType',false);"
                ng-model="restrictedPartyInfo.customerTypes"
                style="position: relative; align: center; top: 1px; left: 245%; width: 150%; height: 65px;"
                ng-init="customerTypess ='val_customerTypess'" >
                    <option ng-repeat="custtyp in customerTypes" value="{{custtyp.clientTypeCode}}">{{custtyp.clientTypeCode}} – {{custtyp.clientDescription}}</option>
                </select>               
            </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

For 1.
Use **Multiple** tag of html , You have to use Ctrl + mouse click
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_multiple
and you will get array of selected data which use can show in Comma Seprated Way

For 2.
Use can use loop after selection of multiple data from dropdown
You can restrict during Selection like if already in array then remove, NG-change may help
Remove duplicate data coming from Server :)

Comment: Thanks Ritesh for the reply.
Ok, I use Multile to select the option. But As I mentioned I am having one input box where I need to enter selected value. with removing duplicate one.

Comment: Is it required to show duplicates in selection list, can't you remove it from server, For showing , show it using comma separated 
use ngchange on select list, get value, use join with "," and set it in other model which will reflect it on textbox,
You want two way bind on textbox as well?